# how insert a void function as a parameter of another method

Tags: c#, class, methods

Due to different visual class explanation 
please help me on the explain value.

```
private static void method1 (string Value1, int Value2, ??? Method2)
```

Comment: technically, it would be a `delegate`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Action` or `Action<T>`

```
private static void method1 (string Value1, int Value2, Action Method2)
```